# Cutting a rectangle and recieving a square

Tags: geometry

How can I cut a $1 \times 10$ rectangle $7$ times so that I can receive a square?
 I have tried doing it, but wasted lots of paper.

Comment: Can the structures be piled up one above other?? You need one square or 10 squares of same dimension??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: 1x10]

Worth a thousand words, they say.

Comment: Nice – but the question said to cut the rectangle seven times.

Comment: Come on. You can make as many unnecessary cuts as you want, then glue them back.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in the image below uses 4 cuts. None of the pieces needs to be rotated.

It is generated using a dissection based on a strip: imagine layering the long, thin rectangle across the square and cutting at the edges of the square.

[image: Image showing a 5-piece dissection of a long rectangle to a square]

If exactly 7 cuts are needed, the extra cuts can be added arbitrarily.